# problem in display incompletely wp site on local host

Tags: wordpress, web, iis, xampp, localhost

I used to work with my wp site without problems before but I have a problem now and that is that my site is displayed without style(just html) on local host.
-I think the problem occurred after installing IIS or Microsoft SQL Server or VisualStudio.
-I also stopped the IIS through the "IIS Manager" but the problem was not resolved.
-I use xampp.
Please help me get my site fully running again on local host.

Comment: What error message did you see in web browser develop tool? Have you installed static content feature? If Static content is not installed then IIS will not return correct content type.

Comment: Jokies-ding, I didn't find any error message. The only problem is that only the html code is read.Please tell me what changes to IIS Manager?

Comment: Returns error 404 (not found) for css files (and js and etc) . But why?!!!